# Convert XML from a URL to String

Tags: xml, vb.net

I need to get the XML data from [a URL](http://kunder.apsis.se/APIv3/Input/AddSubscribersFromXmlToQueue_xmldata_namemaping_false.xml) and put it all into a string. Please show me the best way to do that. I know how to do this in Java but now I want it in VB.Net Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search in Google the first result is http://vb.net-informations.com/communications/vb.net_read_url.htm:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim inStream As StreamReader
        Dim webRequest As WebRequest
        Dim webresponse As WebResponse
        webRequest = webRequest.Create(TextBox1.Text)
        webresponse = webRequest.GetResponse()
        inStream = New StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream())
        TextBox2.Text = inStream.ReadToEnd()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). The latest build is avalable at the [NuGet project page](http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack).

Downloading your string then would be as simple as:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://kunder.apsis.se/APIv3/Input/AddSubscribersFromXmlToQueue_xmldata_namemaping_false.xml");

// This is your xaml file content as a single string
string xmlAsString = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;a string
```

I am not familiar with VB.NET, but this sure should not be any problem to translate. :-)

Comment: @Pedram: I just found that this code has troubles with your given URL in particular. It seems that the XML header line is missing which makes it malformed. Do you have the access to it to complete the XML and make it well-formed?